# Change default Python 3 from Python 3.x to Python 2.7 on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: python

My Ubuntu uses python 3.4 as default python. Now I need to use python 2.7. The problems is it's difficult to clearly find out how to switch the default python version , and that numerous libs was installed with python 3.4- which makes python 2.7 unsupported.
Could anyone help me?

Comment: What do you mean by "default" version? Do you mean the version that is run when using the `python` command?

Comment: yes, and everything related to python was installed along with that "default" version

Comment: This question is probably more suited for a exchange like [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) or [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) since it's more about setting up the environment than solving a programming problem.

Comment: if you simply need to run python2, you indeed may invoke it as `python2`. If you need that programs which don't care about a particular python version use python2, then you may to use `update-alternatives` to change the link `python3 -> python` to `python2 -> python`

Comment: libraries for both python versions don't interfere with each other because 2 python versions have different python lib paths (`/usr/lib/python2.x` and `/usr/lib/python3.x` and the package manager takes care of the proper handling them.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu has something called Dead Snakes repository from where you can install any version of Python, maintained by Felix Krull.

https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/ubuntu/deadsnakes

The best practice is to

- Install Python from deadsnakes PPA
- Create a virtualenv for corresponding Python

  ```
  virtualenv -p python2.7 my-venv
  ```
- Then you use this virtualenv for further Python development and deployment

  ```
  source my-venv/bin/active
  ```

[Read more about Python virtual environments](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/projects.html#virtualenv).

**Do not change anything Python related in /usr/bin or symlinks**. This breaks all your operating system packages depending on Python.